# Transaction Webhook Notification

Tags: braintree

In Braintree documentation it's mentioned that Transactions have two types of notifications: transaction_settlement_declined and transaction_settled. Source: https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/reference/general/webhooks/transaction

Unfortunately in panel settings 'API->Webhooks', there's no option to enable this type of notifications:
[image]

I've tried to enable all options, but still I don't receive these notifications from Braintree servers.

Braintree support is silent, no response for days.

While browsing SO I've found that user [Jerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5199921/jerry) is working for Braintree, but I'm unable to contact him.

Anyone has any idea what's going on with Braintree, why they're not responding?